# GitLab Helm Charts fails deployment using terraform only when replica is set

Tags: gitlab, terraform, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm deploying GitLab Runner through helm provider in terraform and it's all been smooth up until version `0.30.0`. Now when I try to deploy a later version e.g. `0.43.1` I'm getting the issue below. If I do not set the replica, this works fine

A few things that I have tried

- I can see the generated Helm Values with `TF_LOG=trace`, posted below, all looks great
- I've looked at the GitLab Helm Charts, nothing too odd here [on the file that it fails](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/-/blob/main/templates/service-session-server.yaml).
- I can deploy the Helm charts with the exact Values I get from Terraform trace logs if I use Helm directly without any issues, only fails if I use Terraform
- Neither new Helm Charts installation through terraform works nor Helm upgrades through Terraform
- I have tried deploying with different formats on the replica, e.g. `2.0`, `"2"`, `"2.0"`,
- I have tried with providing `type` on `set` block for `replicas`, both with `auto` and `string`, none made a difference

Error message

```
 helm_release.gr_helm_release: Creating...
╷
│ Error: template: gitlab-runner/templates/service-session-server.yaml:1:12: executing "gitlab-runner/templates/service-session-server.yaml" at <eq (default 1.0 .Values.replicas) 1.0>: error calling eq: incompatible types for comparison
│ 
│   with helm_release.gr_helm_release,
│   on main.tf line 14, in resource "helm_release" "gr_helm_release":
│   14: resource "helm_release" "gr_helm_release" {
│
```

Values file from terraform trace
logs.

```yaml
gitlabUrl: (sensitive value)
rbac:
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - apps
    - extensions
    resources:
    - '*'
    verbs:
    - get
    - list
    - watch
    - create
    - patch
    - delete
    - update
replicas: 2
runnerRegistrationToken: (sensitive value)
runners:
  name: runner
  serviceAccountName: gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner
  tags: test
```

Original terraform block

```
resource "helm_release" "gr_helm_release" {
  name       = "gitlab-runner"
  repository = "https://charts.gitlab.io"
  chart      = "gitlab-runner"
  version    = var.gr_helm_chart_version
  namespace  = var.gr_ns
  set {
    name  = "replicas"
    value = var.gr_replicas
  }
  set_sensitive {
    name  = "runnerRegistrationToken"
    value = var.gr_iac_registration_token
  }
  set_sensitive {
    name  = "gitlabUrl"
    value = var.gr_gitlab_url
  }
  set {
    name  = "runners.name"
    value = "test"
  }
  set {
    name  = "runners.tags"
    value = replace(local.runner_tags, ",", "\\,")
  }
  set {
    name  = "runners.serviceAccountName"
    value = var.gr_service_account_name
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.create"
    value = true
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.clusterWideAccess"
    value = true
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.serviceAccountAnnotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = module.stack_deployment.iam_admin_arn
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.rules[0].apiGroups"
    value = "{${join(",", local.rbac_rules_map.rule_0.rbac_rules_apigroups)}}"
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.rules[0].resources"
    value = "{${join(",", local.rbac_rules_map.rule_0.rbac_rules_resources)}}"
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.rules[0].verbs"
    value = "{${join(",", local.rbac_rules_map.rule_0.rbac_rules_verbs)}}"
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.rules[1].apiGroups"
    value = "{${join(",", local.rbac_rules_map.rule_1.rbac_rules_apigroups)}}"
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.rules[1].resources"
    value = "{${join(",", local.rbac_rules_map.rule_1.rbac_rules_resources)}}"
  }
  set {
    name  = "rbac.rules[1].verbs"
    value = "{${join(",", local.rbac_rules_map.rule_1.rbac_rules_verbs)}}"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that the `eq` operator is actually using `1.0` which is a floating point number: `eq (default 1.0 .Values.replicas) 1.0`. Terraform should be able to support using `2.0`. Have you actually tried setting it to `2`?

Comment: You may need to file this with the helm provider issue tracker.

Comment: @MarkoE, yes, the value that I set, is actually 2, which is what we can see in the rendered Values file.